# What is the name of the product set containing a set?

Tags: notation

If I have a set $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$, then I can define a set like so

$$
\{x \in \mathbb R^n : \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, n\} \ \exists \ y \in \Omega \quad \textrm{s.t. } x_i=y_i \}
$$

which is the (probably smallest) product set in $ \mathbb R^n$ containing $\Omega$. Is there a name for such a set?

Comment: Do you mean just the union of all of the projections of $\Omega$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $\pi_i$ with domain $\Omega$ such that, for each element $x$ of $\Omega$, $\pi_i(x) = x_i$, is sometimes called the $i$th projection map of $\Omega$. The range $X_i$ of $\pi_i$ is sometimes called the $i$th projection of $\Omega$.  Your set is equal to the product set $\prod_i X_i$, so you could call it the product of the projections of $\Omega$.